# SFTP session factory

Tags: spring

I'm using `org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory` in my spring-beans.xml

But it is showing the error in xml file.

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Class 'org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory' not
   found
- Class 'org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory' not
     found [config set: OnlineOrderAPI/web-  context]
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Add to your pom.xml

```
        <dependency>    <!-- necessary for using sftp -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-sftp</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

then you are ready to go, if not,

right click project, maven, update project
clean project
restart eclipse
etc etc etc